# Regular plane curves such that the line they determined is mutually orthogonal to both

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Let $\alpha(t)$ and $β(t)$ be two regular plane curves such that the line determined by $\alpha$ and $β$ is mutually orthogonal to $\alpha$ and $β$.

Is it really this simple to prove that the segment of line between $\alpha$ and $β$ at t has constant length? Since that line is mutually orthogonal to $\alpha$ and $β$, then we can write (assuming, without loss of generality, that $\alpha$ and $β$ are reparameterized by arclength):

$\alpha - β = kn_\alpha(t) = k_1n_β(t)$, where $n_\alpha$ and $n_β$ are the unit normal vectors to $\alpha$ and $β$. Then:

$|\alpha - β| = |k| = |k_1|$ .

EDIT: Some minor corrections I should have included earlier

Comment: No one says that the curves have constant curvature! [If you want more details, see exercise 20 in section 1.2 of my text. Such curves are called *Bertrand mates*.] Moreover, and this is a big deal, if $\alpha$ is arclength-parametrized, it's very rare that $\beta$ will have the same arclength parameter!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, by k and and k1 I didn't mean to refer to the curvatures, sorry. They are just arbitrary constants.

Comment: But you're supposed to *prove* that these are constants. You can't just say they are!! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin But since the line is mutually orthogonal to both, then shouldn't it's directional vector be parallel to both the normal vectors of the original curves?

Comment: Sure. So write down a parametrization of $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $n_\alpha$. Now what?

Comment: I still don't get what's wrong with my original proof. Doesn't the equality I wrote hold precisely because the vectors are parallel (using the definition that two vectors are parallel if one is a multiple of the other)?

Comment: I actually was thinking in $\Bbb R^3$, rather than in $\Bbb R^2$, but, regardless, I am repeating myself here. Yes, $\alpha-\beta$ is a scalar multiple of $n$, but why is that scalar multiple a constant function?

Comment: @TedShifrin

Sorry for the (additional - I now see why my original assumption lacked a proof -) mistake above (already deleted it). Actually $\beta = \alpha - kn_\alpha$. I also know that:

$(\alpha(t) - \beta(t))\cdot \alpha'(t) = (\alpha(t) - \beta(t))\cdot \beta'(t) = 0.$

But I'm having trouble to getting to the conclusion that $k$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incredibly obvious eluded me (thanks, Ivo):

$(||\alpha - \beta||^2)' = 2(\alpha' - \beta')\cdot (\alpha - \beta) = 2((\alpha - \beta)\alpha' - (\alpha - \beta)\beta') = 2\cdot0 = 0$ since everything inside the parenthesis is 0 (which follows from the fact that the line they determine is mutually orthogonal to both). So $||\alpha - \beta||^2 = c$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$.